# If Core Graphics uses Metal under the hood, can a Metal implementation run faster than a CG one? Why?

Tags: performance, core-graphics, metal

Let's say I want to develop a Paint app and need to implement a brush engine. For a raster brush, you basically need to stamp a texture on touch locations with a given spacing.

-- **Task**: Composite a small image (brush tip) over a bigger one.

I decided to build a prototype first in CG using a *CGContext* to render the stamps and found out it performed pretty well even with coalesced touches and a decent size canvas (CGContext output size).

However, since I need to paint onto really big textures (8000x6000 would be great), I decided to give metal a chance. I know that this task might be trivial for someone with a background in Metal but I'm new in this field. So I tried to use *CIFilters* (Metal backed) for compositing the brush over the canvas and displaying it in a custom MetalImageView: GTKView.

I thought having the canvas and the brush as *CIImages* and displaying them in a Metal Layer would already be more performant than the naive CG implementation. But it's not. The CIFilter approach renders the entire canvas every single stamp(at: Point), whether in CG I just refresh a small rect around that point.

Now, I think I could accomplish that with the CIFilter if I could change the extent that is computed. I don't know if that can be done with Core Image, but I'm sure in metal would be really easy for someone with experience.

-- **Question**: Can a pure metal implementation be faster stamping images than the CG one, given that CG runs with Metal under the hood? If so, how faster? Is it worth learning how to do it, or should I better spend that time improving the CG implementation?

Note that I'm asking for a raster brush, not a vector brush with Bezier Paths which is way easier to code and runs faster but textured brushes can't be used.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: CoreImage is not Metal, the implementation you describe depends entirely on how core image filters are implemented. Metal is a low level drawing API, I can tell you that it is much faster than other approaches. But, you are comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Thanks for replying. A Core Image Filter is a wrapper for a Core Image Kernel which are written in Metal Shading Language. Correct me if I'm wrong, but writing a custom CIKernel in Metal and calling it from a subclassed CIFilter, taking the resulting CIImage, and rendering to a subclassed MTKView with a CIContext isn't considered "Metal"?

Comment: Yes, the CoreImage API is different than Metal. The difference is easy to see in that you can implement a low level approach in Metal, and it works just fine for even huge buffers. But, implement that same approach on top of CoreImage and you could see massive performance problems. Here is an example of that, it shows source code for the exact CoreImage on top of Metal type of call you describe, and the performance is awful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431826/skeffectnode-combined-with-cifilter-runs-out-of-memory

Comment: The "direct" Metal approach should be faster, of course, but I didn't think there would be a massive difference with this other APIs also based on Metal and working on the GPU. I have to agree with you in that if I want top performance I should be using the best tools for the job anyways. I guess it's time to learn Metal properly. Could you point me to any relevant Metal tutorial for my task? I've seen most of them trying to accomplish things in 3D. I just want to load a blank canvas or image onto a MTLTexture, and stamp another texture over it. Thanks!!

Comment: Stamped instance rendering: http://metalbyexample.com/instanced-rendering/

Comment: If you want to render with Metal, I suggest you start with MTKView and skip all the previous API interfaces as rendering directly is the fastest approach. A real world working example can be seen in the this iOS example, showing rendering of video frames into a MTKView: https://github.com/mdejong/MetalBT709Decoder

Comment: But, keep in mind that you may be able to get perfectly fine performance with plain CoreGraphics API calls, it really depends on your situation. CoreGraphics is a completely different API than Metal or CoreImage, these APIs each come with trade offs and performance issues. Metal is harder to get working for the first iteration, but you can manage performance to a stunning degree. Other Apple APIs only do what they are designed to do, often you are stuck if you try anything fancy.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a [chapter in the Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_feedback_based/ci_feedback_based.html) about that. They describe continuous painting into the same texture using the `CIImageAccumulator` class. You can also download the [sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CIMicroPaint/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009218).

I think performance-wise there shouldn't be a huge difference. You should be able to optimize heavily by telling Core Image the [region of interest](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_advanced_concepts/ci.advanced_concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH9-SW12) and domain of definition (`extent`) of your brush stroke filter. Then it should be able to render only the necessary parts of the image instead of the whole thing in every frame.

Comment: That implementation is pretty close to what I was trying to do, without the CIImageAccumulator, which I didn't know existed. I still have to read it in depth but sounds promising, thanks! So far, I've been trying to stamp textures to a quad in Metal and while it works it's much more complicated than using Core Image, as expected.

Now, when it comes to implementing the ROI in metal, is there any way to do that? Because the fragment shader will be computed in every pixel of the image/quad. What if I wanted to update only a small rect? Maybe just do a passthrough in the pixels out of ROI?